# Consuming Netflix REST API with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, rest, restkit

I am trying to fetch some data from Netflix REST API from my iOS app. I haven't worked with REST web services before and am not too conversant with it. After a frenetic search it appeared that the most convenient way to do it is through RestKit. However, I am having trouble in installing RestKit. I am using Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 5. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Is installing something like RestKit really the only convenient way to consume a REST web service from an Objective-C code?

Comment: Please be more specific about the trouble you're having with the installation.

Comment: Hi Josh, followed all the steps and then tried inserting an '#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>' in the view controller file, but got a compile error which said 'RestKit/RestKit.h not found'. Alternately, if you can point me to the right set of instructions for installation I will verify it once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an installation guide in the [wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x), and in the [readme](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/README.md), additionally there is a [guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.9.3-to-0.9.4-dev) to upgrade from the older version, if that's applicable to you. There is also the install guide on the [development](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/README.md) branch, which you failed to specify if you were using.

If `RestKit.h` cannot be found, it probably means your header search paths are not configured correctly.

Comment: I am unclear on what was the purpose of the various steps in the installation guide, but it worked. Not sure how long it takes before one even starts to understand the installation instructions. Thanks again.